# How can I find out whether a bounty was offered on a question in the past?

Tags: support, bounty, api

I'm doing some data analysis on Stack Overflow questions, and I would like to figure out if a bounty was offered on a question or not.
Is there a way to look at a question and figure this out? Is there an API on Stack Overflow that allows this?

Note: I'm not talking about currently active bounties.

For example, I had offered a bounty on my question in the past ->
[Streaming video from Camera to Samsung Smart TV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16729114/streaming-video-from-camera-to-samsung-smart-tv), but now when I look at it, I see no traces of a past bounty.

Comment: Take a look at the revision history of the question.  For the question you linked, the revision history is at http://stackoverflow.com/posts/16729114/revisions

Answer (score 4):

While the [answer from zcoop98](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/412683)  leverages the API, for data analysis of larger sets the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) might be a viable alternative.

This [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1504911?questionid=16729114) for example answers your specific question:

```sql
select votes.postid [Post Link]
     , userid [User Link]
     , votes.creationdate [Bounty started] 
     , votes.bountyamount
     , postnotices.creationdate [Notice added]
     , postnoticetypes.Name
     , postnotices.body
from votes
inner join postnotices on votes.postid = postnotices.postid
inner join postnoticetypes on postnoticetypes.id = postnotices.postnoticetypeid
where postnotices.postid = ##questionid##
and votetypeid = 8 -- bounty added
```

Which gives us:

[image]

From here you can adapt to include more questions.

SEDE is refreshed once a week on Sunday.

Answer (score 3):

It's not the most intuitive, and could certainly be more streamlined, but you *can* use the API to determine if a given question has ever been bountied, all you need to do is to pull the **revision history** for that post (*not*, as one might assume, the post *timeline*).

The [API endpoint for this is `/posts/{ids}/revisions`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/revisions-by-ids#ids=16729114&filter=default&site=stackoverflow), where `{ids}` can be 1 to 100 semicolon delineated post IDs.

Using the post in question as an example, we'll send a GET request to:
`https://api.stackexchange.com/2.3/posts/16729114/revisions?site=stackoverflow`, which returns us a response containing an array of [revision-type objects](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/revision), sorted by creation date (most recent first), wrapped in the standard [SE API response wrapper](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/wrapper).

Unfortunately, there isn't a single "isBounty" field or similar to help us identify bounty revisions in the list, so we have to resort to parsing the `comment` field for this information (a string representation of the HTML used for the bounty notice in the post's revisions list).

Thankfully, the `comment` string of all bounties appears to take the same format:

```html
<b>Bounty Started</b> worth <span class=\"s-badge s-badge__bounty s-badge__sm\">{bounty_amount}</span> reputation by <a href=\"{user_url}\">{user_display_name}</a>
```

Given this, we can simply check whether the comment exists and starts with `<b>Bounty Started</b>` to tell if the given revision notice belongs to a bounty.

If the response contains at least one such entry, then the post has had at least one bounty in its history.

Snippet example below:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      ids: '16729114',
      pulled: false,
      loading: false,
      bounties: [],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    async pullRevs() {
      this.bounties = [];
      this.pulled = false;
      this.loading = true;

      await this.$nextTick();

      let response = await (await fetch(`https://api.stackexchange.com/2.3/posts/${this.ids}/revisions?key=U4DMV*8nvpm3EOpvf69Rxw((&site=stackoverflow`)).json();
      for (revision of response.items) {
        if (revision.comment && revision.comment.startsWith('<b>Bounty Started</b>'))
          this.bounties.push(revision.creation_date);
      }
      this.pulled = true;
      this.loading = false;
    },
    getDate(timestamp) {
      return new Date(timestamp * 1000).toString();
    },
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2/dist/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <h2>Has post been bountied?</h2>
  <p>(eg. 16729114, 26217076, 69770733, etc.)</p>
  <input placeholder="Post ID" v-model="ids" type="number">
  <button :disabled="ids.length == 0" @click="pullRevs">Go!</button>
  <div v-if="loading">
    <p>Loading...</p>
  </div>
  <template v-else>
  <div v-if="pulled && bounties.length">
    <h3>Yes!</h3>
    <h4>{{ bounties.length + ' time' + (bounties.length > 1 ? 's' : '') + ':'}}</h4>
    <ul>
      <li v-for="bountyTime in bounties" :key="bountyTime">{{ getDate(bountyTime) }}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div v-if="pulled && !bounties.length">
    <h3>No.</h3>
  </div>
  </template>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at the [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/16729114/timeline) of the post.

[image]

You will see a table containing the history of the post, and the row that has the "bounty started" *(and "notice added")* is when the bounty was placed.

[image]

Comment: This question is about how to do so via the API.

Comment: @RyanM Although the question includes *"Is there an API on Stack Overflow that allows this?"*, it didn't say specifically that it must be done via API. Note the *"For example, I had offered a bounty on my question in the past, but now when I look at it, **I see no traces of a past bounty.**"* in the OP's post.

Comment: It's also tagged [meta-tag:api], which is for "The Stack Exchange application programming interfaces (the “API Services”) are a set of programming interfaces which can query and connect to Stack Overflow and other sites in the Stack Exchange Network."